# web3.eth.accounts.decrypt throws error at cryp.createDecipheriv

Tags: vue.js, smartcontracts, web3js

I was creating a simple Dapp using Web3 and Ethereum Test Network. I'm trying to decrypt a version 3 Keystore JSON file but I'm getting error

```
this._web3.eth.accounts.decrypt( JSON.parse(jsonfile), "test123456789");
```

The error is like this

```
cryp.createDecipheriv is not a function
```

I'm using the 1.0.0-beta.34 version.

The weird thing here is this is happening on my angular app.

When I created a Test app in VueJS. the decrypt function succeeded.

I done the same procedure with the both of it

```
npm install web3 --save

npm run-script build
```

and followed how it will be used in the documentation

http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=encrypt

My question is, why this error is occurring on my angular app but its working on my vue app. I want to make this work on angular app too but unfortunately no luck.

All I've seen info regarding this is this
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1071
But I don't understand what to do here

Answer (score 0):

I decided to edit the index.js from web3-eth-accounts and change the

```
var cryp = (typeof global === 'undefined') ? require('crypto-browserify') : require('crypto');
```

into just

```
var cryp = require('crypto-browserify');
```

It works now. But I still don't know whats wrong with my angular set up. The vue app has the same code but it is working.